# NestJS + Angular project throws Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cache-manager'

Tags: angular, server, swagger, nestjs

I have a NestJS backend (6.9.0) and Angular frontend project (8.2.11).
I use concurrently to start the front end and backend in parallel in my localhost.

The backend starts fine (starts faster) but when the Angular project starts compiling and when the compilation is ready it throws the following error:

Any ideas why ?

This has worked fine before, unfortunately I can not pinpoint exactly what changes caused this behavior. In NestJS I am not using the cli, I build it just with tsc.

```
WARNING in ../server/node_modules/@nestjs/common/utils/load-package.util.js 8:39-59
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

ERROR in ../server/node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache/cache.providers.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cache-manager' in '/mnt/c/codes/salesforce-compare/server/node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache'
ERROR in ../server/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'class-transformer' in '/mnt/c/codes/salesforce-compare/server/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes'
ERROR in ../server/node_modules/@nestjs/common/serializer/class-serializer.interceptor.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'class-transformer' in '/mnt/c/codes/salesforce-compare/server/node_modules/@nestjs/common/serializer'
ERROR in ../server/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'class-validator' in '/mnt/c/codes/salesforce-compare/server/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes'
```

Comment: It seems that when I build the angular project it also starts building the nestjs project. I have a top most folder and under that client, server and shared folders, when I go into the client folder and run ng serve it compiles also the server project in server folder. There are separate node_module folders in client and server folders. Any idea what is causing this ?

Answer (score 11):

Looks like some of your nestjs packages was imported in angular application.

I also encountered this issue. In my case, I shared entity classes with `@ApiProperty` annotations from `@nestjs/swagger` for both backend and frontend apps.

Comment: that's indeed the problem. but then the question is, how do we share the entities and at the same time have Swagger work as needed?

Comment: @Eugen may my I answer help you too?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: In my case,  I did an `@Inject()` and it pulled in `@Nestjs/common` instead of `@Angular/common`

Answer (score 9):

This happens when trying to import parts of a package which are not designed for being incorporated in a final bundle (like `ApiProperty` for the case of @chshanovskiy and me).

This is a common issue when trying to mix Nest.js and JS based front-end parts (in my case: Angular in an Nx workspace) and there is an interesting discussion about it in the Nest project itself [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1706#issuecomment-579248915).

After reading carefully and trying the strategies described in the previous issue, I finally solved it by changing the way I architecture my dependencies, here is an explanation about the working file system I ended with:

```
├── apps
│ ├── back // <- Nest.js app
│ ├── front // <- Angular app
├── libs
│ ├── back
│ │ ├── service-1 // <- Nest.js library (publishable)
│ ├── front
│ │ ├── service-1 // <- Angular library (NgRx feature, publishable)
│ ├── interfaces
│ │ ├── service-1 // <- Node.js library (publishable)
```

- `back / service-1`: Nest.js library, using Swagger annotations (especially `ApiProperty`). Each DTO Class also implements an homologue interface coming from `interfaces / service-1`
- `front / service-1`: Angular library calling Nest.js APIs and specifying its interface contract with types coming from `interfaces / service-1`
- `interfaces / service-1`: Standalone Node.js library exporting interfaces / types which needed to be share between `back / service-1` and `front / service-1`

This way, both back and front depend are on same interfaces and there is no need to use Nest.js parts somewhere else than in their own places: the `back/*` libs and apps.

Comment: Did you also try the "externalDependencies" Option to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a quick starter project and avoid this kinda of troubles, I have made some Angular / NestJS boilerplate project fully dockerized and ready to deploy to production server.

I am sharing there: https://github.com/godardth/typescript-fullstack-boilerplate

Hope that helps :)