# How can I add an Object to type in ApiBody decorator in nest js

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I have a controller with a POST operation to save ReasonCode. Here is what I have in my controller:

```js
import {
  CustomAuthGuard,
  ReasonCodeService,
  ReasonCode,
} from 'cnv-ms-core';

export class ReasonCodeController {
    constructor(private readonly reasonCodeService: ReasonCodeService) {}
}

  @Post('reason-codes')
    @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Save Reason Code' })
    @ApiBody({
        //type: ReasonCode,
        description: 'Reason Code',
        required: true,
        isArray: false,
    })
    @ApiResponse({
        status: 201,
        description: 'Reason Code is Saved Successfully.'
    })  
  async saveReasonCode(
    @Body() newReasonCode: ReasonCode,
  ): Promise<ReasonCode | null> {
    return this.reasonCodeService.saveReasonCode(newReasonCode);
  }
```

Here is my interface object:

```js
export interface ReasonCode {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    type: ReasonCodeTypeEnum;
    isVisible: boolean;
    createdAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
}
```

As you can see in the above snippet of my controller, I commented out the 'type' in the '@ApiBody' decorator. I wanted to add this, but when I uncomment I see the error 'ReasonCode only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here' and vs code offers the quick fix to add ReasonCode to imports. But, I already have ReasonCode in imports. How can I add this in the @ApiBody to see it in swagger-ui.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: why not create a DTO class rather type with all api properties?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an interface to add a type to the body you should use a class to do that and then just add the @ApiProperty() decorator to each property of the class, it's a cleaner solution because you can avoid the @ApiBody() Decorator.

Also, when using a class you can take advantage of the class validator decorators to validate the body before using it.

*ApiProperty is exported from @nestjs/swagger*

More info here: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters#types-and-parameters

Also check this info about class-validator: https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#class-validator

Comment: I changed it to a class and now I see the below errors:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cache-manager'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'class-transformer'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'class-transformer/storage'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'class-validator'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'express'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fastify-swagger'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path'

Comment: Install the packages with the command:  npm i class-validator class-transformer

Comment: Also, are you using express or fastify with nest ?

Comment: And let me see your class to check if everything is ok

Comment: I had installed class-validator and class-transformer.         "@nestjs/swagger": "^4.8.0",
        "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
        "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
        "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6" is from my package.json. Here is the class
export class ReasonCode {
    @ApiProperty()
    name: string | undefined;
    @ApiProperty()
    description: string | undefined;
    @ApiProperty()
    type: ReasonCodeTypeEnum | undefined;
    @ApiProperty()
    isVisible!: boolean | true;
    createdAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
}

Comment: I still see the errors:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cache-manager' in '/home/nnookala/git/nvc-next/nvc-ms-shared/node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'class-transformer/storage' in '/home/nnookala/git/nvc-next/nvc-ms-shared/node_modules/@nestjs/mapped-types/dist'

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'express' in '/home/nnookala/git/nvc-next/nvc-ms-shared/node_modules/swagger-ui-express'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fastify-swagger' in '/home/nnookala/git/nvc-next/nvc-ms-shared/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/nnookala/git/nvc-next/nvc-ms-shared/node_modules/swagger-ui-dist'

Comment: That's a really weird error, are you using webpack or monorepo mode on your project ?

Comment: And, I repeat my initial question, Are you using express or fastify with nest ?

Comment: monorepo mode and using express. Thanks.

Comment: Mmm ok are you mixing the backend and the frontend (Maybe Angular) in the same folder or near ?

Comment: Sorry for asking this. How can I find about this? I am new to nest js development and trying to implement swagger as I worked in java development before. I think I came across the post that mentioned about mixing backend and frontend when searched for one of the errors. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest your error messages are pretty weird, I have implemented swagger on several nestjs project and I never saw something like that, just try to search the errors because this seems to be a problem of folder instead of a nestjs problem, check the if the routes of the errors exists i.e /home/nnookala/git/nvc-next/nvc-ms-shared/node_modules/swagger-ui-dist. And make sure that the decorator are imported from the right folder, also check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58779725/nestjs-angular-project-throws-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-cache-ma

Answer (score -1):

changing `export interface ReasonCode` to `export class ReasonCode` might solve this